# Contact Form - Invalid email address entered! - Allow it to go through

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a contact form on my simple HTML/PHP/CSS site, and I want to allow people to send their contact message even if they don't submit their email.

But everything I tried, when I submit a message through the contact form, it either returns some errors, or it returns the following error: "Invalid email address entered!"

Here is my contactprocess.php

```
<?php

include("../config.php");

if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['Email_Address'];
$error ="";
$errors ="";

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error.="Invalid email address entered!";
    $errors=1;
}

if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array ('Link','Quantity','Your_Message');
    $required = array('Link','Quantity','Your_Message');


    $email_subject = "The Message";
    $email_content = "new message:\n";

    foreach($values as $key => $value){
      if(in_array($value,$required)){
        if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
          if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
        }
        $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
      }
    }

    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        header('Location: http://example.com'); 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}
?>
```

I'm sure it's a simple edit, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: just match the email field with some regex to validate the email.

Comment: Noob question - how would I do that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code explicitly prevents in going through & adds the error if the email is invalid?

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $error.="Invalid email address entered!";
   $errors=1;
}
```

then

```
if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{ // other stuff
```

If you don't want that behavior, wouldn't the simplest option be to just remove that code?

Or is the idea, if they do submit an email it must be valid - else allow it through if there is none. In which case your if should be something like

```
if (!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
```

Comment: Jesus Christ. Yes, removing that bit of code did it. I swear on everything I love, I played with that code, and I'm pretty sure I even tried removing it, and I still had errors. Anyway, that did it. Thanks Carl :)

Comment: No prob's :) Glad to hear I helped.